# Add plugin dependency in grails

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin, plaid

I am trying to add dependency of a plugin into my grails application, but it doesnot have any plugins in grails repo. It can be added to maven project as :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
  <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

As my project is also maven based. How do i add this plugin into my project.

P.S. : IT cannot be added in plugins and dependencies since there is no grails plugin associated with that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `create-pom org.mycompany` to create your **pom.xml** file to make grails read the **pom.xml** you need to set in **BuildConfig.groovy** this code

```
 grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   /*YOUR CONFIG*/
   pom true
   repositories {
     /*YOUR RESPOSITORIES*/
   }
}
```

Then you need to add your dependency in this **pom.xml**

You can see the official doc. in this [link](http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/create-pom.html)

Answer (score 1):

We can add dependency for any plugin in grails under `dependencies{}` in BuildConfig.groovy as:

```
<groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version>
```

For your case, the equivalent for:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
  <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

is:

```
dependencies{
      compile "com.plaid:plaid-java:0.2.12"
}
```

For more you can have a look into http://docs.grails.org/2.3.1/guide/conf.html